# vue.set() an array in a vuex mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to vue.set() an array in a "updateInformation" mutation in my vuex store.

Here is my function in my script:

```
 updateImagesArrayInMutation(imageFile) {
      let images = [];
      this.images.forEach(imageFile => {
        imageFile.generateBlob(
          blob => {
            let rand = (Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 16) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 16)).toUpperCase()
            let imagesRef = firestorage.ref('postimages/' + rand)
            console.log("imageRef, imageFile for eachfile", imageFile)
            if(this.images.length < 3) {
              // THIS PUSHES AN EMPTY CROPPA ("CLICK DRAGE IMAGE HERE") // max 5
              this.images.push({})
              console.log("imagesRef", imagesRef.fullPath)
            }
            this.updateImages ({ 
              images: imagesRef.fullPath
            })
          },
          'image/jpeg',
          0.8,
        )
      })
    },
    updateImages(images) {
      console.log("this is value from closure", images)
      this.updateInformation({
        images: images,
        title: this.post.title,
        description: this.post.description
      })
    },
```

This is the mutation in my store:

```
  [UPDATE_INFORMATION] (state, info) {
    console.log('[STORE MUTATIONS] - UPDATE_INFORMATION:', info)

    Vue.set(state.newPost.images, 'images', [...info.images])

    // state.newPost.images = info.images
    state.newPost.title = info.title
    state.newPost.description = info.description
    state.newPost.location = info.location
    state.newPost.city = info.city
  },
```

Can I do this? Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What is the initial state of the `newPost` object when your store is created?

Comment: newPost: {
    images: '',
    title: '',
    description: '',
    location: '',
    city: ''
  },

Comment: Are you trying to create an `images` property inside an `images` property? I'd guess you just want `Vue.set(state.newPost, 'images', [...info.images])`.

Comment: i get an: "Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance"

Comment: That suggests that `info.images` is not an array. Difficult to know what to suggest without knowing why you're trying to spread a non-array into an array. If `images` is just a string then why are you involving arrays at all?

Comment: its not an array yet, its the first value in an array, with more to come as the user adds them 1 by 1 to be an array in updateInformation. there will be images array as a value in the updateInformation object.

Comment: @skirtle but i guess there is my issue, it's not an array yet... so i need to store an array in like session or something, and then async all imageRefs at the same time to be in the updateInformation mutation ?? just not understanding fully here. thanks.

Comment: and @JasonSmith, do images in initial state of newPost object need to be images: {} ?

Comment: @TeomanKirac see my answer below. Also, skirtle makes a good point in their answer regarding the method you use to prepare the data before committing the mutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know some of the libraries you're using but I think I understand what you're trying to do. In short, you're trying to replace multiple calls to mutate the store state with a single call that passes an array of image paths.

Switch the first few lines to use Promises, like this:

```js
const imagePromises = this.images.map(imageFile => {
  return imageFile.promisedBlob('image/jpeg', 0.8).then(blob => {
```

Then inside the `then` callback return the relevant image path rather than calling `updateImages`:

```js
return imagesRef.fullPath
```

This will give you an array of Promises that resolve to the paths you want. You can then use `Promise.all` to wait for all the Promises:

```js
Promise.all(imagePromises).then(imagePaths => {
  // imagePaths should be an array of strings
  this.updateImages(imagePaths)
})
```

That should get you the array of path strings that you want.

Comment: i see! think this is the answer, will give it a try and respond. Just really quickly however I can't get it to "return imagesRef.fullPath" for some reason..  will get back after i do more thorough attempt. . thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do it like this:

```js
[UPDATE_INFORMATION] (state, info, payload) {
    state.newPost = {
        ...state.newPost,
        ...info
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work, but the example is bad. If the state is large, then it will be completely renewed, and not partially.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to use `Vue.set()`. The purpose of `Vue.set()` is to add new properties to an object, not to change existing properties.

In your Vuex initial state, it would make most sense to me to initialize this way:

```
newPost: { images: [], title: '', description: '', location: '', city: '' }
```

Now your images property is an array, as expected, rather than a string.

In the `UPDATE_INFORMATION` mutation, you can do either:

```
state.newPost.images = info.images
```

Or:

```
state.newPost.images = [...info.images]
```

If you want a shallow copy of the `info.images` array instead of referring to it directly.